# Track returning visitors' source

Tags: google-analytics

An affiliate website sends traffic to a shop, which should compensate it for purchases up to 90 days after the first visit.

To calculate the compensation, the shop produces with GA a conversion report based on traffic source, but it seems to be excluding returning customers (which account for about 55%).

How is it possible to ensure the original traffic source gets retained for at least 90 days?

Comment: In Google Analytics the traffic source for a session changes with every visit that is no a direct type in. You can create a user based segment of the "sequence" type and set it to "interaction type: first interaction" whith the condition of "campaign source equals <affiliateid>" (assuming you used utm campaign parameters for affiliate tracking), and this will return all users for which the first contact was via your affiliate. But this is a  reportig issue and might very well be off-topic here (better ask at webmasters@stackexchange.com if you need more details).

Answer (score 0):

Try this report: Conversions > Multi-Channel Funnels > Assisted Conversion. After that select 90 days range:
[image]

For this to work you need to have custom Conversion Segments set up properly. Check it out, i think you will find youre solution there.